# IndexError: list index out of range while index exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the NOI 2018(National Olympiad of Informatics Netherlands) I need to solve a coding problem.

My program receives an even integer N between 3 and 17 from stdin.
Then it generates an array with N/2 zeros and N/2 ones (like [0,0,0,1,1,1])
Then it generates all permutations of that array in lexicographic order and stores it in another array.
Then it removes the duplicates, because my function to generate all permutations generates duplicates.

Than it removes all items which don't meet the criteria that there may not be more than two of the same values next to each other.

Then it returns the count of items left and then outputs each item.

Here is my code:

```
N = int(input('N:'))

def genPermutations(num, index):

    if len(num) - 1 == index:

        if num not in rows:

            rows.append(num)

    for i in range(index, len(num)):

        newList = num[:]
        temp = newList.pop(i)
        newList.insert(index, temp)
        genPermutations(newList, index + 1)

num = []
rows = []

for j in range(2):

    for i in range(int(N) // 2):

        if j == 0 :

            num.append(0)

        else:

            num.append(1)

genPermutations(num, 0)
rows = list(set(map(tuple, rows)))

for i in reversed(range(len(rows))):
    rows[i] = list(rows[i])

    for j in range(len(rows[i]) - 2):

        if rows[i][j] == 1 and rows[i][j + 1] == 1 and rows[i][j + 2] == 1:

            rows.pop(i)

        elif rows[i][j] == 0 and rows[i][j + 1] == 0 and rows[i][j + 2] == 0:

            rows.pop(i)

print(len(rows))

for i in reversed(range(len(rows))):

    string = ''

    for j in range(len(rows[i])):

        string += str(rows[i][j])

    print(string)
```

Now the problem is that when I enter N = 6 the program returns an error.
With all other values for 3 < N < 17 it is working

Comment: Doesn't work for N = 7 as well as N = 6.

Comment: @LukeWoodward N is an even integer, see the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced the problem with a simple `print` statement:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(rows))):
    rows[i] = list(rows[i])
    for j in range(len(rows[i]) - 2):
        print("i=", i, "j=", j, len(rows), "rows;", len(rows[0]), "cols")
        if rows[i][j] == 1 and rows[i][j + 1] == 1 and rows[i][j + 2] == 1:
            rows.pop(i)
```

Output:

```
i= 19 j= 0 20 rows; 6 cols
i= 19 j= 1 20 rows; 6 cols
i= 19 j= 2 20 rows; 6 cols
i= 19 j= 3 19 rows; 6 cols
```

... and there's your problem.  You removed a row from the table while you were still trying to process that row.  You need to also `break` out of the `j` loop when you do that.  In the two clauses:

```
    if rows[i][j] == 1 and rows[i][j + 1] == 1 and rows[i][j + 2] == 1:
        rows.pop(i)
        break

    elif rows[i][j] == 0 and rows[i][j + 1] == 0 and rows[i][j + 2] == 0:
        rows.pop(i)
        break
```

This yields the expected answer of 14 permutations.

This failed only on `N=6` because that's the only set for which the final permutation gets deleted.  Print out the final lists for each value of N, and you'll see ...

Comment: Thanks! When I added `break` to the `j` loop it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in reversed(range(len(rows))):
    ...
        rows.pop(i)
```

Don't remove items from a list while you're iterating over it.

`len()` is only calculated once, at the top of the loop, so when you shorten the list during the loop execution, you end up trying to iterate over items that aren't there anymore.

Comment: I reversed the range, so this should be a problem. And for N = 4, 8, 10, 12, 14 and 16 it does work

Comment: The OP isn't actually iterating over the list they're removing items from.  They're iterating over a `range` object created from the initial length of the list.